# AJAX Autocomplete validation

Tags: php, html, ajax, autocomplete

I have successful autocomplete with AJAX,PHP,MYSQL for getting city name from database.It allows both autocomplete value and typed value in the text box.But i want to allow only autocomplete value when user typing on the textbox.Please correct javascript for to make empty the textbox when user came out from textbox after typed the city name their own.

following are html and js code

---

```
<input type="text"  id="city" name="locality"  style="padding:1px;" required="">
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#outer_container').height($(window).height());

        $('#city').autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'ajax.php',
                    dataType:"json",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        name_startsWith: request.term,
                        type:'city'
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            console.log(item);
                            //var code = item.split("|");
                                return {
                                    label: item,
                                    value: item,
                                    data : item
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
            },
            autoFocus: true,            
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                /* $('#myButton').show();
                var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
                $(this).val(names[1]);
                getClientAddress(names[0]); */
            }               
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You can use focusOut event of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use select2 plugin instead of autocomplete.
You can check example here https://select2.github.io/examples.html